# Entity Framework 5 - Nullable Enum is ignored when Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework, enums

Doing code-first migrations with pure POCOs.

Here is my class:

```
[Table("Contact")]
public class Contact
{
   public int Id { get;set; }
   public string Name { get;set; }
   public Prefix? Prefix { get;set; }//added this one then perform Add-Migration
}

public enum Prefix
{
    Gen,
    Dr,
    Ms,
    Mr,
    Mrs,
    Prof,
    Rep,
    Sen,
    St
}
```

I added the Prefix Enum but when performing Add-Migration simply ignores it?

Answer (score 2):

Enums in general are not handled by EF and need to be converted to int or string. It is however supported by EF5 BUT only on .Net 4.5

See article by Julia Lerman http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/video-entity-framework-5-enums-and-moving-solution-from-ef-4-3/